# Exception when When using

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio

I have a winform application which contains a datetimepicker. When I select a date it gives that date sale details. I have added the code to form load event also, but I get a SqlDateTime overflow error. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

my code is

```
  DateTime fromDate, toDate;
            DateTime.TryParse(dateTimePicker_FromByDateSaleReport.Text, out fromDate);
            DateTime.TryParse(dateTimePicker_ToByDateSaleReport.Text, out toDate);


            SqlDataAdapter da3 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Bill_Date,Name,Item,Item_Code,MRP, Quantity,Amount as Total, Amount_After_Discount as Grand_Total  From POS  LEFT JOIN Customers ON POS.Customer=Customers.Customer_Id WHERE Bill_Date Between @From AND @To", con);
            da3.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@From", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = fromDate;
            da3.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@To", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = toDate;
            DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
            da3.Fill(dt);
            dgv_ByDateSaleReport.DataSource = dt3;
        }
```

.

Comment: You might be passing null in date params

Comment: Did you output dateTimePicker_FromByDateSaleReport.Text? What does it say? Which date format does it contain?

Comment: You don't need to parse out the value from the picker - you can just retrieve it with the [Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value(v=vs.110).aspx) property. Don't think that's the problem, but it might help.

Comment: DateTime can't be null @husnain_sys

Comment: Why is this question upvoted? The issue could be easily solved, if the asker had debugged it just one time. The code is not properly formatted. We are left to guess which date caused the overflow. And this has nothing to do with Visual Studio. So why is it upvoted? This question is of low quality.

Comment: Iam a newby. So take it easy if u can.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you should read this article. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: @Abhijith then learn how to debug first and read the rules of SO. http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking You could easily solve the issue by yourself if you had looked what are the values of `fromDate` and `toDate`. If you have a specific question, we are glad to help, but this question reflects only laziness.

Comment: I have to complete a project tomorrow! so some errors making me crazy. so i thought of asking here.

Answer (score 3):

This can happen for one of two reasons:

Firstly, either the `fromDate` or the `toDate` is out of that range, or (most likely):

One of your date variables (either `fromDate` or `toDate`) could not be parsed by the `TryParse()`.  When this happens, the date is set to the default `C#` value of `0001-01-01`.

In `SQL Server` a `DATETIME` datatype can only hold values from `1753-01-01` to `9999-12-31`, and the `0001-01-01` that was being passed is out of range.

Check the value of the strings being parsed prior to execution.

Comment: Or, better, don't use the string values at all, and just get the DateTime that the picker will [give you directly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value(v=vs.110).aspx)! Nice psychic debugging by the way ;)

Answer (score 1):

This could be caused by your `fromDate` and `toDate` values not properly being parsed, and thus likely containing their original default value of "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM", which won't be a valid date :

```
DateTime fromDate, toDate;
DateTime.TryParse(dateTimePicker_FromByDateSaleReport.Text, out fromDate);
DateTime.TryParse(dateTimePicker_ToByDateSaleReport.Text, out toDate);
```

If you are using a DateTime picker control, you could likely access the date by using the [`DateTimePicker.Value` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value(v=vs.110).aspx), which will return an actual `DateTime` object :

```
DateTime fromDate = dateTimePicker_FromBydateSaleReport.Value;
DateTime toDate = dateTimePicker_ToByDateSaleReport.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, `SqlDbType.DateTime` has a value ranging from January 1, 1753 to December 31, 9999, so you should try to use `SqlDbType.DateTime2` instead.
Also, no point of parsing the `DateTimePicker.Text` property to `DateTime`, since it already has a DateTime property called `Value`.

Try this instead:

```
        SqlDataAdapter da3 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Bill_Date,Name,Item,Item_Code,MRP, Quantity,Amount as Total, Amount_After_Discount as Grand_Total  From POS  LEFT JOIN Customers ON POS.Customer=Customers.Customer_Id WHERE Bill_Date Between @From AND @To", con);
        da3.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@From", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = dateTimePicker_FromByDateSaleReport.Value;
        da3.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@To", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = dateTimePicker_ToByDateSaleReport.Value;
        DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
        da3.Fill(dt);
        dgv_ByDateSaleReport.DataSource = dt3;
```

Comment: can i insert into datetime typed column with parameters as cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BillDate", dateTimePicker_POS.Text); Iam getting error message as "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: Didn't see that you where using `AddWithValue`, changed that to `Add`. Anyway, the more important thing is that you don't need to use the `Text` property at all since you have a `Value` property.